# Call a function in main file from module using python

Tags: python, class, function

I am trying to make a python script that works so:

I've got a main file that import another file, which is a class with functions inside it.
The main file calls a function in the module, here it works all well, but when the def inside the module calls another def in the main again, I get an error.

For example, in main.py I've got this

```
from module import *
module = Example()

def foo():
 module.foo2()

def foo3():
 print "here is the problem"

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
 foo()
```

In module.py I've got:

```
class Example():
 def foo2(self):
  foo3()
```

foo2 is called perfectly, but when I try to call foo3() I get a NameError (global name 'foo3' is not defined). I know I should import it somehow but I don't know how to do it.

Last thing: I am quite new to python so please explain good :-)
Thanks

Comment: I assume  `if(if __name__ == "__main__"):` is a typo, and the outer `if(...)` should be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid creating circular dependencies and refactor your code such that foo3 is either in module, or another new module.  For example (I cleaned things up a little bit as I went along to follow [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)):

main.py

```
import module
example = module.Example()

def foo():
 module.foo2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 foo()
```

module.py

```
import module3

class Example():
    def foo2(self):
        module3.foo3()
```

module3.py

```
 def foo3():
     print "here is the problem"
```

If you absolutely must keep the circular dependancy, then the best way to handle it would be to move the import in module.py to the end of the file as suggested on [effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).  Again, I would avoid doing this at all cost.

```
class Example():
 def foo2(self):
  main.foo3()

import main
```

Comment: Wow! So many answers! I'll try this too and see what's happen!

Comment: The above only works for me if I use: from main import foo3 at the bottom of module.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for catching that.  IMHO, it would be preferred to use import main, then main.foo3() rather than from main import foo3.  To quote the Zen of Python "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!".

Comment: yes, for me too. But if you want to use it in the way he explain you can also write main.foo3() instead of foo3()

Comment: Haha same explanation :-) However, you answer is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Again, I can't imagine a situation in which you'd be writing two modules that depend on one another like that.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.  Just a friendly nudge since it appears that you are new.  Be sure to select one of the answers here as correct once you decide which one is the best solution in your situation.  It helps build reputation, and is one reward mechanism for those that post answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You want foo3 in main to be called from module? This will work in the module:

```
class Example():
    def foo2(self):
        from main import foo3
        foo3()
```

However, I'm not sure what this buys you in module (how useful such a circular dependency is), since the two modules now tightly depend on each other. I imagine you want the Example class to be able to use the foo3 function from any caller.

I would do something like pass the function into the class:

```
from module import *
module = Example()

def foo():
    module.foo2(foo3)

def foo3():
    print "here is the problem"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

Then in module.py:

```
class Example():
    def foo2(self, myFoo):
        myFoo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the late reply, but I've found a very elegant, albeit 'hackish' solution:

In you main module you can add this:  (No need for the recursive imports...)

```
module.foo3 = foo3
```

It has the effect that `foo3` is now a defined thing in `module.py`, even though you have never declared it within that file!  Try it.  It works.

I encountered this situation where I want to put my GUI interface in another file, but the GUI obviously has to call functions in the main module.  So I found this solution, out of desperation :)